# Retrieving the content of a collection after fetch

Tags: backbone.js, fetch

I am trying to retrieve my models from the local storage in a collection. I enter into "success" but sometimes my collection is still empty. I thought "success" meant the collection was well fetched.

```
    var self = this;
    window.rooms= new Rooms();
    window.rooms.localStorage = new Backbone.LocalStorage("rooms-backbone");
    window.rooms.fetch({
        success: function(model, response, options) {
            rooms.each(function(room){
                this.template = _.template(tpl.get('RoomView'));
                $(self.el).append(this.template(room.toJSON()));
                console.log(rooms.toJSON());

                console.log(model);
                console.log(response);
                console.log(options);
            });
        }
    });
```

How can i populate my UI once i am sure the collection is well filled ?
Thx in advance

Comment: hmm .. `success` does mean that the records have been fetched. Are you sure your data point is returning data correctly?

Comment: it seems that my models were not saved yet on my previous view. So i suppose there were nothing to fetch